# how to load the gpu trained model into the cpu?

Tags: gpu, conv-neural-network, pytorch, cudnn, pre-trained-model

I am using PyTorch. I am going to use the already trained model on multiple GPUs with CPU. how to do this task?

I tried on Anaconda 3 and pytorch with cpu only i dont have gpu

```
model = models.get_pose_net(config, is_train=False)
gpus = [int(i) for i in config.GPUS.split(',')]
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model, device_ids=gpus).cuda()

print('Created model...')
print(model)
checkpoint = torch.load(config.MODEL.RESUME)
model.load_state_dict(checkpoint)
model.eval()
print('Loaded pretrained weights...')
```

the error i got is

```
    AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call  last)
<ipython-input-15-bbfcd201d332> in <module>()
      2 model = models.get_pose_net(config, is_train=False)
      3 gpus = [int(i) for i in config.GPUS.split(',')]
----> 4 model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model, device_ids=gpus).cuda()
      5 print('Created model...')
      6 print(model)

C:\Users\psl\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in cuda(self, device)
    258             Module: self
    259         """
--> 260         return self._apply(lambda t: t.cuda(device))
    261 
    262     def cpu(self):

C:\Users\psl\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in
```

_apply(self, fn)
        185     def _apply(self, fn):
        186         for module in self.children():
    --> 187             module._apply(fn)
        188 
        189         for param in self._parameters.values():

```
C:\Users\psl\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _apply(self, fn)
    185     def _apply(self, fn):
    186         for module in self.children():
--> 187             module._apply(fn)
    188 
    189         for param in self._parameters.values():

C:\Users\psl\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _apply(self, fn)
    191                 # Tensors stored in modules are graph leaves, and we don't
    192                 # want to create copy nodes, so we have to unpack the data.
--> 193                 param.data = fn(param.data)
    194                 if param._grad is not None:
    195                     param._grad.data = fn(param._grad.data)

C:\Users\psl\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in <lambda>(t)
    258             Module: self
    259         """
--> 260         return self._apply(lambda t: t.cuda(device))
    261 
    262     def cpu(self):

 C:\Users\psl\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\cuda\__init__.py in _lazy_init()
    159         raise RuntimeError(
    160             "Cannot re-initialize CUDA in forked subprocess. " + msg)
--> 161     _check_driver()
    162     torch._C._cuda_init()
    163     _cudart = _load_cudart()

C:\Users\psl\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\cuda\__init__.py in _check_driver()
     80 Found no NVIDIA driver on your system. Please check that you
     81 have an NVIDIA GPU and installed a driver from
---> 82 http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx""")
     83         else:
     84             # TODO: directly link to the alternative bin that needs install

AssertionError: 
Found no NVIDIA driver on your system. Please check that you
have an NVIDIA GPU and installed a driver from
http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To force load the saved model onto cpu, use the following command.

```
torch.load('/path/to/saved/model', map_location='cpu')
```

In your case change it to

```
torch.load(config.MODEL.RESUME, map_location='cpu')
```